# Php : check if user login matches the email

Tags: php, email

So let me explain, I'm building a forget password system.

My goal is this one : if the user loses his password, he can recover it by providing his login and his email and then receiving an email message that will contain a random password.

So, he could log with this new one and change it to his new personal one inside his profile page : I have already made a changing password system and it works.

---

The thing is, I would like to make sure that the email matches the user login, else anyone could put a random email, and so a registered user could have his current password reset...

So how to do, to verify that the email that we put in the form : $_POST['mail'] matches the user's one in the database by checking his login?

I know we can do that for the password just like this with **password_verify** :

```
// Getting the user login

$sql = "SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login = :login";
$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(['login' => $_POST['username']]);
$row = $result->fetchObject();


// Checking the password

if($result->rowCount() == 1 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $row->password)) {/* */}
```

Is there an **email_verify** that does the same thing?

Comment: do not send random password, send a link in email when that link click perform the rest task

Answer (score 0):

The email isn't hashed like a password, so all you need to do is a simple string comparison.

You can use `strcasecmp`.

See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php